# which of following shapes are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

which of following  shapes are homeomorphic ?

[image]

i think shapes 1 and 5 are homeomorphic so 2 and 4 are homeomorphic , and 6 and 4 are not homeomorphic because if we remove an interior point from shape 6 we have two component  connected and if we remove an  point from shape 4 we have one component  connected (for every point). are 3 and 4 homeomorphic ?

Comment: Consider starting at a given point in figure 3 and tracing the curve in one direction.

Comment: @anomaly, I can't understand your reason.

Comment: The process I described gives a map. Show it's a homeomorphism.

Comment: @anomaly. very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow the surface to intersect with itself while moving, you can show that 3 and 4 are homeomorphic.

6 is not homeomorphic to any other shapes. It may be mapped continuously to a circle but the converse is not possible.

5 is homeomorphic to 1 for similar reasons.